# How to use WHERE IN in Rails 3 that works across database systems?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, where-in

I am quite to new to Rails and have marginal experience with SQL-type languages.

I am working on a Rails 3 project where my test-version of the product and my project manager's version of the product use two different database systems (I use MySQL but I'm not sure what he uses).

I have here a generic SQL statement that I want to work on BOTH of our databases.  Is there any way to do this through just the ActiveRecord functionality?

```
SELECT * FROM MyRecords 
WHERE  (f1, f2, f3, f4) IN (
    SELECT f1, f2, f3, f4
    FROM   MyRecords
    GROUP  BY f1, f2, f3, f4
    HAVING count(*) = 1 
);
```

In other words, I am trying to execute a "WHERE IN" statement (and to be frank, I don't even know what a WHERE IN statement does, just that this answer does what I need: [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns-postgresql) )
To be more specific, I have to augment the following ActiveRecord function so that it does the above query:

```
  def MyRecordFunction
    MyRecords.where('org_id=?', self.org_id).order('f4')
  end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the ActiveRecord Guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

There is some info on there about specifying conditions on joins and such like.

Can't be more specific because you haven't shared what the other DB you want compatibility with.